# How to loading/show a picture in a Python CGI page

Tags: python, html, cgi

I have written a little survey using Python and CGI. I am trying to show a picture using the normal  `<img>` tag, But even-though the picture is in the same directory as my cgi script, my script cannot show it. I also changed the header to this:

```
print "Content-type: text/html; image/jpeg"
print
print """<html> 
<head>
<title>You are going to be redirected</title> 
</head> 
<body bgcolor = #14b585>
<br>
 <p align=center><font>Helloooo</font></p>
 <img src="cat.jpeg" alt="cat" width="304" height="228"/> 
 <form action="./sample.py" method="post">
<p align=center><input type="submit" value="YES!" /></p>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

"""

Why?(it is a very small jpg file)

Comment: Should we guess what the rest of the code looks like?

Comment: I added the rest, hope it helps

Comment: What does the URL of the image show up as in the browser?

Comment: it just show the place holder of the photo with a broken pic icon and a text .

Comment: yes, that's what i understood..didn't get what exactly u mean

Comment: I did this in my browser: http://localhost/cgi-bin/cat.jpg and it got an error, I checked the logs, it Exec format error: exec of '/home/hossein/public_html/cgi-bin/cat.jpg' faile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print "Content-type: text/html; image/jpeg"
```

Don't change the header to that. You can't have multiple content types for a single document (multipart documents excluded, but browsers don't support them and that isn't the right format).

You are delivering an HTML document with an reference to an image in it. The image will be a separate request and response.

```
print "Content-type: text/html"
```

Or, better:

```
print "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

(Assuming you are using utf-8, which you should be).

```
print """<html>
```

Your Doctype is missing. This will trigger quirks mode, which is undesirable. You also have a great deal of legacy presentational markup that should be replaced by CSS.

```
<img src="cat.jpeg" alt="cat" width="304" height="228"/>
```

The context suggests that the image is decorative, so the alternative text should probably be `""` (see [Alt texts in IMGS](http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/alt/alt-text.html)), but there is nothing wrong with the actual reference to the image.

> But even-though the picture is in the same directory as my cgi script

Since the HTML seems to be OK. You need to check that the image is.

Can you reach the image by typing the URL in directly?

What do the web server logs say when you try?

It is possible that your server is configured to try to treat everything in the directory as an executable, no matter what the file extension, so it might be trying to run the image as if it were a CGI program (which will obviously fail). If so, then you could either move the image or change the configuration of the server.

And I've just noticed this comment:

> I did this in my browser: localhost/cgi-bin/cat.jpg and it got an error, I checked the logs, it Exec format error: exec of '/home/hossein/public_html/cgi-bin/cat.jpg' failed

That is what is happening. Moving the image is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

your apache was configured to use the cgi-bin directory as an CGI scripts folder, so any request that trying to get a file from this folder apache try to execute it as an CGI script. to make your image visible move it to the www/html folder.