# How to display image in Python-cgi

Tags: python, html, cgi, content-type

I am beginner and i dont know where i am doing mistake. i have seen these stack posts [Return an image to the browser in python, cgi-bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198093/return-an-image-to-the-browser-in-python-cgi-bin) , [Return Image from python CGI using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21688393/return-image-from-python-cgi-using-javascript) and [How to loading/show a picture in a Python CGI page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149681/how-to-loading-show-a-picture-in-a-python-cgi-page) but got no help.

Here is the code:

```
#!C:\Python27\python

text = """Content-type: text/html\n

<TITLE> CGI 101 </TITLE>
<H1>A SECOND CGI SCRIPT </H1>
<HR>
<P> HELLO,CGI WORLD!</P>
<img src="../imag000.jpg" width=101 height=64 border=0 alt="">
<HR>
"""

print (text)
```

and on browser it appears small box which is not showing image, like this:

[image]

Kindly help.

and folder which contains image is **cgi**. Kindly see picture:

[image]

Comment: The mime type of your data isn't image/png but text/html. If you change that, provided you have the image at the location you specify, it should show up.

Comment: but picture is not coming

Comment: here is my update: 

#!C:\Python27\python

text = """Content-type: text/html\n

<TITLE> CGI 101 </TITLE>
<H1>A SECOND CGI SCRIPT </H1>
<HR>
<P> HELLO,CGI WORLD!</P>
<img src="../imag001.jpg" width=101 height=64 border=0 alt="">
<HR>
"""

print (text)

Comment: see pic for understanding http://tinypic.com/r/10p4toh/9

Comment: I am. Try structuring your html as it should be structured. With the proper header, doctype, etc.

Comment: I am not currently able to write it for you. Take a look at this: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html

Comment: structuring?? you mean i shd write print '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">' 

print '<html>' 
is that u saying??

Comment: but the text is printing but not image.

Comment: i did place <html> and <body>  tags but no result :(

Comment: kindly help i am getting fail every time but still trying ....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96607/discussion-between-fran-borcic-and-user3440716).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the best Solution:

```
<img src="http://localhost/imag000.jpg" width=101 height=64 border=0 alt="">
```

Comment: yh thanx for appreciating my own effort :)

Answer (score 0):

The HTML claims that the image is in the parent directory, but the server has it in the same directory. Either modify the HTML to match the current image location, or move the image to where the browser is requesting it from.

Comment: i am sorry i did nt understand where is browser if requesting from? phpmyadmin folder?

Comment: ummm i am doing on python-cgi by placing "Content-type: text/html\n"

Comment: That's nice. Read the HTML.

Comment: u mean i shd create html pages?

Comment: i think u saying i dont know html? whereas my question is how shall i use <img src="imag000.jpg" > in cgi bcz text is coming nicely.

Comment: You use it exactly the same way as you would with HTML. Because you're generating HTML.

Comment: yes. but if i write in this way "<img src="../New folder/cgi/imag000.jpg" width=101 height=64 border=0 alt="">" still no pictures appears